# Jenkins docker container immediately stop

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins

I run a Jenkins with: `docker run --name jenkins jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11`  and

```bash
docker run --name jenkins \
           -p 8090:8080 \
           -p 50000:50000 \
           -v /app/jenkins/home:/var/jenkins_home \
           -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker \
           -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
           jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
```

Either which way I use to run Jenkins, Jenkins's container will also immediately stop with output:

```bash
[lighthouse@VM-4-6-centos jenkins]$ docker run --name jenkins jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11

Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war

webroot: /var/jenkins_home/war

2023-04-24 06:29:51.240+0000 [id=1]     INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file

2023-04-24 06:29:52.862+0000 [id=1]     WARNING o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#setContextPath: Empty contextPath

2023-04-24 06:29:52.975+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-10.0.13; built: 2022-12-07T20:13:20.134Z; git: 1c2636ea05c0ca8de1ffd6ca7f3a98ac084c766d; jvm 11.0.18+10

2023-04-24 06:29:53.592+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor#visitServlet: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet

2023-04-24 06:29:53.691+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.s.DefaultSessionIdManager#doStart: Session workerName=node0

2023-04-24 06:29:54.528+0000 [id=1]     INFO    hudson.WebAppMain#contextInitialized: Jenkins home directory: /var/jenkins_home found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")

2023-04-24 06:29:54.888+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStart: Started w.@39c385d6{Jenkins v2.387.2,/,file:///var/jenkins_home/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/jenkins_home/war}

2023-04-24 06:29:54.915+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.server.AbstractConnector#doStart: Started ServerConnector@74a6a609{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}

2023-04-24 06:29:54.946+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: Started Server@3543df7d{STARTING}[10.0.13,sto=0] @4795ms

2023-04-24 06:29:54.959+0000 [id=23]    INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Winstone Servlet Engine running: controlPort=disabled

2023-04-24 06:29:55.432+0000 [id=30]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started initialization

2023-04-24 06:29:55.464+0000 [id=28]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Listed all plugins

2023-04-24 06:29:56.886+0000 [id=29]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Prepared all plugins

2023-04-24 06:29:56.893+0000 [id=29]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Started all plugins

2023-04-24 06:29:56.928+0000 [id=29]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Augmented all extensions

2023-04-24 06:29:57.337+0000 [id=31]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: System config loaded

2023-04-24 06:29:57.338+0000 [id=31]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: System config adapted

2023-04-24 06:29:57.338+0000 [id=31]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Loaded all jobs

2023-04-24 06:29:57.340+0000 [id=31]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Configuration for all jobs updated

2023-04-24 06:29:57.452+0000 [id=44]    INFO    hudson.util.Retrier#start: Attempt #1 to do the action check updates server

WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/var/jenkins_home/war/WEB-INF/lib/groovy-all-2.4.21.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)

WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1

WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations

WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

2023-04-24 06:29:58.528+0000 [id=30]    INFO    jenkins.install.SetupWizard#init: 

*************************************************************

*************************************************************

*************************************************************

Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.

Please use the following password to proceed to installation:

8446a405736949e296a069a227d5a31c

This may also be found at: /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword

*************************************************************

*************************************************************

*************************************************************
```

I tried to set /app/jenkins/home mode 777, or don't mount volume or don't expose ports, the problem have not solved

I tried run `docker start container_id -i` I did not found any output more

Comment: I just tried to restart the server and Jenkins works